# Arithmetics with void pointer

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

I call a function  that swaps shifts a massage in memory:

```
        for (int i = now->size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
           void *address2 = prev->start_address + i;
           void *address1 = now->start_adress + i;

           address1 = address2;
           address2 = '\0';
        }
```

So basically I have  two addresses one pointing to the first start location the other to the second start location that the content have to be pasted.
The problem is that the only solution that I find is to add `int` ( this is i value ) and `prev->start_adress`( that is void*) as I have shown. I want to do it correctly, i cant change the void pointer to int. Is there any other possibilities.

My errors:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
 warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arit]
  214 |                void *address2 = prev->start + i;
Warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arit]
  215 |                void *address1 = now->start + i;
```

Supporting information:
I have a linked list(full of segementdescriptors) and a "memory" that is a simple array[].Similar how malloc works.

```
typedef struct segmentdescriptor

{
   Byte allocated;
   void *start;
   size_t size;
   struct segmentdescriptor *next;
} Node;
```

the start pointers point to the begining of the allocated space in the array[].

**Update:**
The simplest way is to use typecast to do arithmethics on void pointers if you know their size like :

```
char *address2 = (char *)prev->start + i;
```

If you dont know the type, it is impossible because for example:
`char *pointer` points to one byte of memory and if you write `pointer++`  goes
to next byte. `int *pointer` is lets say points four byes. if you write `pointer ++` goes to the four bytes after the four bytes.

There are also good answers below.
Thanks for all answers.

Comment: You can't do arithmetic on void *.  How would it know how much to add?

Comment: "i cant change the void pointer to int" why? you should be able cast it to `int` (or any other integer datatype that is able to hold a pointer without data loss) and then cast it back to a `void*`

Comment: start_adress is pointing to the first adress in memory that have to be copied

Comment: The usual solution is to cast `void*` to `char*`.

Comment: Also, I don't think that they want to add i to the address pointed to by the poiners, but offset the address by i to get a different address

Comment: `void *address1 = now->start_adress + i;` but you discard the assigned value in the very next assignment `address1 = address2;` And what about `address2 = '\0';` it suggests you intend to assign a char value to a pointer variable. I think you missed a few dereference operators. Have you considered using `memcpy` or `memmove`?

Comment: I'd love to swap a massage too, on occasion (meaning: You probably mean *messages*, and it's unclear what you are trying to do -- you don't swap anything in the code presented). But more seriously: If you ask about type problems **it would really help to see the declaration of the variables involved**, and also the definition of the actual objects.

Answer (score 1):

I do not really understand what ***`shifts a massage in memory`*** is, but if you just want to copy one memory location to another you can

1. Use `memcpy` or `memmove` (if memory locations overlap)

   ```
    memcpy(now->start_adress, prev->start_address, now->size);
   ```
2. Write your own function to copy the memory

```
void *mymemcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t size)
{
    unsigned char *cdest = (unsigned char *)dest;  //cast for C++ compiler
    const unsigned char *csrc = (unsigned char *)src;

    while(size--) *cdest++ = *csrc;
    return dest;
}
```

```
void *mymemcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t size)
{
    unsigned char *cdest = (unsigned char *)dest;  //cast for C++ compiler
    const unsigned char *csrc = (unsigned char *)src;

    for(size_t index = 0; index < size; index++) cdest[index] = csrc[index];
    return dest;
}
```

```
void *mymemcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t size)
{
    unsigned char *cdest = (unsigned char *)dest;  //cast for C++ compiler
    const unsigned char *csrc = (unsigned char *)src;

    for(size_t index = 0; index < size; index++) *(cdest + index) = *(csrc + index);
    return dest;
}
```

C standard does not allow any pointer arithmetic on `void` pointers. `gcc` has an extension which treats the `void *` as pointer to char allowing the arithmetics, but not allowing dereferencing.+

Comment: in the first version of `mymemcpy()` you forgot to increment `csrc`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding these warnings:

```
 warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arit]
  214 |                void *address2 = prev->start + i;
Warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arit]
  215 |                void *address1 = now->start + i;
```

On any modern computer the value of a pointer is a memory address (typically a virtual memory address). When you add one to a pointer, it's value (aka the memory address) is incremented by the sizeof the pointed to type.

Example:

```
 TYPE* p = SOME_ADDRESS;  // The value of p is now SOME_ADDRESS
 p = p + 1;               // The value of p is now SOME_ADDRESS + sizeof(TYPE);

 p = SOME_ADDRESS;        // The value of p is now SOME_ADDRESS
 p = p + i;               // The value of p is now SOME_ADDRESS + i * sizeof(TYPE);
```

In other words: In order to add an integer value to a pointer, we need to know the size of the element that the pointer points to.

And that is your problem. You have void-pointers so you would need to know the "sizeof void" in order to update the pointer. But the sizeof void can be anything and isn't defined by the standard. Apparently, your compiler has a non-standard extension that allows `sizeof(void)`. Consequently, your compiler only gives you a warning.

Regarding this error:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char*’
```

It comes from some code post you didn't post. Further it shows that you use a c++ compiler instead of a c compiler.

Finally: Even if the pointer arithmetic was valid, your code do nothing.

```
    for (int i = now->size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
       void *address2 = prev->start_address + i;
       void *address1 = now->start_adress + i;

       address1 = address2;  // This only change the value of the pointer
                             // It doesn't change the memory that the
                             // pointer points to
       address2 = '\0';
    }
```

It's not fully clear what you are trying to do but perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
    for (int i = now->size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
       char *address2 = (char*)prev->start_address + i;
       char *address1 = (char*)now->start_adress + i;

       *address1 = *address2;
       *address2 = '\0';
    }
```

Comment: It does not matter how pointer is stored and how pointer is represented by the implementation. Pointer arithmetics does not depend on it.

Comment: `Consequently, your compiler gives you a warning.` no in this case compiler knows exactly how it works - because it is gcc family compiler.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland For sure it doesn't but treating pointers as memory addresses helps explain why things are the way the are. And all modern systems work like that.

Comment: Pointer arthmetic is defined only for the same array. It is enough to use the term array element to explain how it works.

Answer (score 0):

The type `void` is always an incomplete type. That is the size of an object of the type `void` is unknown. So you may not use the pointer arithmetic with a pointer of the type `void *` though some compilers have their own language extensions that allow the pointer arithmetic with the type `void *` the same way as with pointers of the type `char *`.

So these statements

```
void *address2 = prev->start + i;
void *address1 = now->start + i;
```

are incorrect according to the C Standard because the pointer `start` has the type `void *`.

Also it seems these statements

```
address1 = address2;

address2 = '\0';
```

are doing not what you thing.

For starters this statement

```
address1 = address2;
```

assigns one pointer to another pointer though it looks like actually you want to assign a value pointed to by one pointer to the memory pointed to by another pointer.

And this statement is equivalent to

```
address2 = NULL;
```

That is it does not set the pointed memory with the terminating zero character `'\0'`.

If as you are saying these pointers deal with a message (a string) then you need to cast the pointers to the type `char *`.

As for this your phrase

> I call a function that swaps shifts a massage in memory:

then it is totally unclear what you are trying to do using the for loop because the loop in any case does not make a sense.

If you need to copy one character array into another character array then use the standard C function `memcpy` or `memmove` depending on what and how you are trying to copy arrays.